# How to decompress non printable tcp packet

Tags: parsing, tcp, packet, pcap, compression

I'm writing a parser to parse tcp data from pcap file.
I found some of the content are non printable, and in my inspection, it is compressed in some way. The following is my packet data content.
Does anyone have idea about how to decompress this packet data...?

```
127.0.0.1:29226 -> 127.0.0.1:7036
^@^F^@^@^G^D^@^@^@^C^B^@^A@^A^@^AL^@^@^@^@P^A^@^@^@^@^@^E^A*^@^@^@^@0^A^@ö20160426^@1009005705^@^@^@^@^@^@0179^@^@^@^@^@^@^@184819^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@Lnx64 FemasAPI v1.01 L300^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@FTDC 0^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@127.0.0.1^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@00:00:00:00:00:00
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@03^@^H^@^@^@^A^@^@^@^@03^@^H^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^@03^@^H^@^@^@^Cÿÿÿÿ03^@^H^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@
```

Comment: It is unknown what kind of data this is (application protocol?), if this just some protocol payload or if these are control information of the protocol. And it is unclear why do you think that these data are compressed - just because they are not printable? In the current form it just dumping some unreadable data without context into the question and asking for help. Therefore I propose to close this question as unclear.

Comment: That does not look compressed at all. There are many repeated zero bytes.